# Uncaught RuntimeException: ObjectManager isn't initialized in vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManager.php on line 31

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-website, index.php

I am trying to write some business logic root folder of `index.php` file, but it's throwing below error.

> Uncaught RuntimeException: ObjectManager isn't initialized in
>   vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManager.php on line 31

I have a multi store based on Country I am redirecting store to appropriate. For these, I have done below code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

//$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$params = $_SERVER;

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$getHelper = $objectManager->get('Learning\Location\Helper\Data');
$getStore = $getHelper->getCountry();

if($getStore == "india"){
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'default';
}else if($getStore == "united states"){
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'us';
}else{
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'us';
}
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store'; // store or website
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

How can I write my logic inside `index.php`? Please suggest us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, worked for me using the below code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$params = $_SERVER;

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$getHelper = $objectManager->get('Learning\Location\Helper\Data');
$getStore = $getHelper->getCountry();

if($getStore == "india"){
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'default';
}else if($getStore == "united states"){
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'us';
}else{
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'us';
}
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store'; // store or website
$bootstrap1 = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);



/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap1->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap1->run($app);
```